# how can i get sale order details of an invoice entry from model account.invoice

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10

I have a new `field` in account.

```
invoice
od_sale_order_name.
```

I need to get the sale order name field value to this field.but i didn't find relation from `account.invoice to sale.order`.

i'm using new api.i have tried to create a relation using code

```
saleorder_ids=fields.Many2many('sale.order', 'sale_order_invoice_rel', 'invoice_id', 'order_id', 'Sale Order')
```

but it doesn't create the field . please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: there is already a char field named "Source Document[tech_name: origin]" in account invoice.

Comment: Can you specify odoo version ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. odoo8